# How can I commit objects instead the current session on EclipseLink?

Tags: eclipse, jpa, eclipse-rcp, eclipselink

I have the current problem: My company has a RCP app which uses EclipseLink, and we make use of `Views` and `Editors`, and the `Editors` have a method called `isDirty()` which points if the current object was changed in any way. My `isDirty()` does something like this

```
if(model != null) // model is the current object beign edited
  return EntityManagerHelper.contains(model) && getRepository().isDirty();
return false;
```

What happens is this: I open an `Editor` (like ProductEditor), change some attribute, then I open another `Editor` (like ClientEditor),  and this second editor open as dirty (like it was already change). Then if I edit the client and save, EclipseLink save the client AND the product on the same transaction. Seems like EclipseLink is commiting the whole session or something like this.
I was reading [this](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Introduction_to_EclipseLink_Sessions_%28ELUG%29#Unit_of_Work_Sessions)

> The unit of work ensures that the client edits objects in a separate object transaction space. This feature lets clients perform object transactions in parallel. When transactions are committed, the unit of work makes any required changes in the database, and then merges the changes into the shared EclipseLink session cache. The modified objects are then available to all other users.

Could `UnityOfWork` change this behavior? If so, how can I implement this pattern?
Did I made myself clear enough? Let me know if someone need some code or more information

Comment: The EntityManager operates the same way as a UnitOfWork with respect to changes, so its not clear what behavior you want to change, or what your code is doing.  If the changes are visible in managed objects, they will be pushed to the database when the the EntityManager is flushed or the transaction commits.  Could it be both EntityManagers are associated to the same transaction, or you are cascading the merge from a client to a product unintentionally?  If you only merge a single entity and commit the transaction immediately after, only that objects changes will be put in the database.

Comment: I have only one EntityManager. The behavior I was talking about is this one, where the `commit` save both `Client` and `Product` objects. Seems like EclipseLink is commiting in a "session level", not in "object level"...

Comment: EclipseLink has native API you can use to issue insert/update object level queries, but it defeats the purpose of JPA and transactional contexts.  You can do the same by just controlling what goes into the EntityManager and flushing/commiting afterward.  Work with detached entities and after your persist/merge call, commit the transaction